# JavaFX changing Locale in whole application

Tags: javafx, locale, resourcebundle

Here is my `StartApp.java`, entry point of my application.

```
public class StartApp extends Application {
private Locale locale = new Locale("en");

public Locale getLocale(){
    return locale;
}

public void setLocale(Locale locale){
    this.locale = locale;
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("resources.bundles/MyBundle", locale);
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("../view/LoginView.fxml"), bundle);
    Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();        
    primaryStage.setTitle("Title");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 750, 400));
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    primaryStage.show();
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    launch(args);

}
```

Then on `LoginController.java` I create instance of StartApp and set onActions for 2 buttons

```
StartApp startApp = new StartApp(); 


@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    bundle = resources;

plBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        try {
            startApp.setLocale(new Locale("pl"));
            changeLanguage(event);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});

enBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        try {
            startApp.setLocale(new Locale("en"));
            changeLanguage(event);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

here is my `changeLanguage` method, which refresh current window and changes its language

```
public void changeLanguage(ActionEvent event) throws Exception{
    ((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow().hide();
    Stage primaryStage = new Stage();

    ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("resources.bundles/MyBundle", startApp.getLocale());
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("../view/LoginView.fxml"), bundle);
        Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();        
    primaryStage.setTitle("Title2");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 750, 400));
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

And till now everything works fine, it changes language once I click buttons. But what I want to do now is to open new window(stage) with choosen language, but unfortunatelly, it always open new scene with language set on StartApp.

Here is method in `LoginController` than opens new stage.

```
public void register(ActionEvent event) throws Exception{
    ((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow().hide();
    Stage primaryStage = new Stage();
    ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("resources.bundles/MyBundle", startApp.getLocale());
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("../view/RegisterView.fxml"), bundle);
    Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();        
    primaryStage.setTitle("Title2");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 750, 400));

    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Btw. Iv tried just extending StartApp to LoginController, making locale public, etc, everytime it ends up the same. When I created

```
Locale newLocale = null;
```

in `LoginController`, and then tried to assign values to it once I click buttons defined in `initialize`, I got nullpointerexception.

Comment: When you reload `LoginView.fxml`, it creates a new controller; in that controller you create a new instance of `StartApp`, and you don't set the locale on that instance. The approach here just seems wrong: it's basically always a bad idea create your own instance of the `Application` subclass: there should be only one instance (the one created for you on which `start(...)` is invoked). Try using a MVC approach for this and include the locale (or perhaps the resource bundle) as a property in the model. Then just share a single model instance with all controllers.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32464974/javafx-change-application-language-on-the-run/32468810#32468810, which is related

Answer (score -2):

I don't know how to change all text by one command.
To keep it simlpe i just rename each element separately.

Example:

*i18n/messages.properties*

```
label.welcome = Welcome
```

*i18n/messages_ukr.properties*

```
label.welcome = Ласкаво просимо
```

*i18n/messages_rus.properties*

```
label.welcome = Добро пожаловать
```

Singleton *Context.java* which will contain current locale:

```
public class Context {

    private final List<Locale> availableLocales;

    private Locale currentLocale;

    private static Context instance;

    public static Context getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new Context();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private Context() {
        availableLocales = new LinkedList<>();
        availableLocales.add(new Locale("eng"));
        availableLocales.add(new Locale("ukr"));
        availableLocales.add(new Locale("rus"));
        currentLocale = new Locale("eng");  // default locale
    }

    /**
     * This method is used to return available locales
     *
     * @return available locales
     */
    public List<Locale> getAvailableLocales() {
        return availableLocales;
    }

    /**
     * This method is used to return current locale setting
     *
     * @return current locale
     */
    public Locale getCurrentLocale() {
        return currentLocale;
    }

    /**
     * This method is used to set current locale setting
     *
     * @param currentLocale locale to set
     */
    public void setCurrentLocale(Locale currentLocale) {
        this.currentLocale = currentLocale;
    }
```

Util class *MessageUtil.java* will return message in current locale (seted in Context):

```
/**
 * This class is used to provide methods to work with localized messages
 *
 * @author manfredi
 */
public abstract class MessageUtil {
    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MessageUtil.class);
    private final static String RESOURCE_NAME = "i18n.messages";

    /**
     * This method is used to return resource bundle with current locale
     *
     * @return resource bundle with current locale. Otherwise resource bundle with default locale.
     */
    public static ResourceBundle getResourceBundle() {
        return ResourceBundle.getBundle(RESOURCE_NAME, Context.getInstance().getCurrentLocale());
    }

    /**
     * This method is used to return localized message by it`s {@code key}
     *
     * @param key message key
     * @return localized message
     */
    public static String getMessage(String key) {
        String message;
        try {
            message = getResourceBundle().getString(key);
        } catch (MissingResourceException e) {
            logger.error("{}", e.getMessage());
            message = key;
        }
        return message;
    }

    /**
     * This method is used to format localized message by it`s {@code key} using {@code args} as arguments list
     *
     * @param key  message key by which the corresponding message will be found
     * @param args list of arguments used in the message
     * @return formatted localized message
     */
    public static String formatMessage(String key, Object... args) {
        MessageFormat messageFormat = new MessageFormat(getMessage(key), getResourceBundle().getLocale());
        return messageFormat.format(args);
    }

}
```

I use SceneBuilder tool for creating *.fxml files.
For example screen controller for one of this files that contain Label and ChoiceBox for language change might looks like following:

```
public class LanguageChangeScreenController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private Label welcomeLabel;
    
    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox<Locale> languageChoiceBox;
    
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        initLanguageChangeListener();
        refreshLocalization(); // I use %key.name syntax in .fxml files to initialize component's names instead of calling this method here
    }
    
    **
     * This method is used to update the name of each component on the screen
     */
    private void refreshLocalization() {
        welcomeLabel.setText(MessageUtil.getMessage("label.welcome"));
    }
    
    private void initLanguageChangeListener() {
        languageChoiceBox.getItems().addAll(Context.getInstance().getAvailableLocales());
        languageChoiceBox.getSelectionModel().select(Context.getInstance().getCurrentLocale());
        languageChoiceBox.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {
            Context.getInstance().setCurrentLocale(languageChoiceBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
            refreshLocalization();
        });
    }
}
```